# Probability estimation and trapezoidal rule

Tags: probability, estimation, sas, monte-carlo, matrix

```
proc iml;

call randseed(4545); * initialize the stream (like streaminit);

x = J(5000,1,.); * pre-allocate space for random numbers;

call randgen(x,'normal',0,1); * fill x with N(0,1) deviates;

y = y + (x**2 - 3*x**3 + 5x < 1);

p = y / 5000;  * MEAN acts on each matrix column;

se = sqrt(y*(1-y)/5000); * VAR, but not STD or STDERR, also acts on columns;

print "IML STEP: estimated mean of sqrt(abs(X)) is" p "with standard error" se;  * use PRINT, not PUT;
```

I'm trying to use monte carlo integration with proc iml to estimate the probability that x**2 - 3*x**3 + 5x is less than 1. What am I doing wrong? Do loops are not allowed by the way.

```
proc iml;

start tr(x,y); * create function called tr;
/* handle bad case */
/*if x<0 then do; return (.); end; * send back missing;*/


N = nrow(x);
dx = x[2:N] - x[1:N-1];
ymean = (y[2:N] + y[1:N-1]) / 2;
return(dx` * ymean );
finish tr;


x = do(-2,5,0.01);
print "Integral of y over x is" ( tr(x,sin(x##2)) );
```

I keep receiving the (execution) invalid subscript or subscript out of range. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
proc iml;
call randseed(45056); *initialize the stream (like streaminit);                     
x = J(2000, 1, .); *pre-allocation space for random numbers;
call randgen(x, 'normal', 0, 1); *fill x with N(0,1) deviates;
y = (x##2) - (3#x##3) + 5#x;
count = ( y <= 1 )[+];  *count of obs where y < 1;
print "Probability that (X**2 - 3*X**3 + 5*X) < 1
        if X is N(0,1) is " (count/2000);
```